Ansible creating an exchange using community.rabbitmq.rabbitmq_exchange task gives 401 Unauthorized error
I'm using the following simple task in Ansible to create a rabbitmq exchange:
- hosts: rabbitmq
  tasks:
    - name: Add my exchange
      debugger: on_failed
      community.rabbitmq.rabbitmq_exchange:
        login_user: "{{ rabbitmq_admin_user }}"
        login_password: "{{ rabbitmq_admin_password }}"
        vhost: "{{ rabbitmq_vhost }}"
        name: "{{ rabbitmq_exchange_name }}"
        durable: true
        exchange_type: direct
        state: present

The task fails with the following error and Ansible enters into debug mode, which I can see the correct password and username is provided:

FAILED! => {"changed": false, "details": "{"error":"not_authorised","reason":"Access refused."}", "msg": "Error creating exchange", "status": 401}

TASK: Add my exchange (debug)>p task.args
...
...
login_password: mypassword
login_user: admin
...

When I ssh into the host ansible is managing and execute a curl command to access rabbitmq management REST API like this, it works and gives me the list of vhosts:
curl -i -u admin:'mypassword' http://localhost:15672/api/vhosts

My rabbitmq version is 3.12.1 and my ansible module version is 1.3.0.
What can be the cause of the problem? Note that mypassword actually contains many different non-alphanumeric characters so I pass it like 'mypassword' to the curl command.
